# How to ignore the connection error in play

Tags: ansible

I want to continue my playbook to do some other tasks when some hosts are unreachable. However, the ignore_errors seems doesn't work. The debug msg is not printed.
ansible version is 2.5.4. Is there a way to do this in this version?

```
- name: check accessibility
  hosts: myhosts
  tasks:
    - ping:
      ignore_errors: yes
    - fail:
        msg: "Host {{ansible_hostname}} is not accessible"
      when: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option would be to ping each '*inventory_hostname*' in the [block](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks) and end the play if the ping fails.

```
- hosts: myhosts
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - block:
        - delegate_to: localhost
          command: ping -c1 "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
      rescue:
       - fail:
           msg: "{{ inventory_hostname }} not accessible. End of play."
    - debug:
        msg: "Host {{ inventory_hostname }} continue play."
    - setup:
```

Notes:

- Set '*gather_facts: no*', because we are not sure all hosts are available
- Use '*inventory_hostname*', because of '*gather_facts: no*'
- use '*setup*' module after the '*block*' if necessary

Running the playbook with available hosts: test_01, test_02, test_03 and unavailable host test_99 gives (abridged):

```
TASK [fail] 
fatal: [test_99]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "test_99 not accessible. End of play."}
TASK [debug] 
ok: [test_03] => {
    "msg": "Host test_03 continue play."
}
ok: [test_01] => {
    "msg": "Host test_01 continue play."
}
ok: [test_02] => {
    "msg": "Host test_02 continue play."
}
TASK [setup]
ok: [test_03]
ok: [test_01]
ok: [test_02]
PLAY RECAP
test_01                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_02                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_03                    : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0   
test_99                    : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=2
```